# Getting root publication of component

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Let’s assume the following publications for this question.

20 Content -> tcm:0-20-1

…

…

…

70 Web     -> tcm:0-121-1

I’ve a component created under (**20 Content**) publication and I’m publishing this component from one of the child publications (**70 Web**). I’m using Dreamweaver template to write UI and I'm calling C# custom functions from DWT. While publishing, this component will be referred as 121-432 in component presentation. Is there any way to get the root publication of where the component is created? That’s I should get 20-432, instead of getting 121-432.

I’ve tried *Component*.GetBluePrintChain() and it returns a list that has all the blueprint hierarchy. I could get 1st item from this list to get this component with the publication where it is actually created.

Since I’ll have to call this method in many places, I just wanted to check if there any other direct/better way to get this done.

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to look at the `OwningRepository` property of the Component, so:

```cs
var componentIdInOwningPublication = new TcmUri(
    component.Id.ItemId,
    ItemType.Component,
    component.OwningRepository.Id.ItemId
);
```

Put that into a custom Dreamweaver-callable function and you should be good to go.

***Update***
There also is a helper method called `CreateTcmUriForPublication` that does the translation. So you could also invoke that one like this:

```cs
var componentIdInOwningPublication = TemplateUtilities.CreateTcmUriForPublication(
    component.OwningRepository.Id.ItemId,
    component.Id
);
```

The end result of both snippets is the same though: the TcmUri of the Component in the context of its owning repository.

Comment: Agree with checking OwningRepository, but I think you got the order of the arguments wrong. In TOM.NET the signature is `public TcmUri(int itemId, ItemType itemType, int publicationId)` for some reason.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've tried this but I'm still not getting the publication id of the component creation level. I'm having a component in 020 publicaton & having a CT in 030 Design publication and while doing preview in 070 Web publication, I'm still seeing tcm id of 070 publication.

Comment: I just tested the code on my own VM and it works fine. Are you sure the Component you're testing with is actually owned by the 020 publication?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen ... It works. Sorry It's my mistake, I missed to notice the changes. Thanks a lot!