# Tridion RepositoryLocalObject.GetBluePrintChain Method (BluePrintChainFilter) thows exception on shared items

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm trying to get a list of parent items that a RepositoryLocalObject (e.g. Component) is inherited from. So if I have a pub ID 1 with component tcm:1-80 and a child pub ID 2, then this component is shared in the child pub as tcm:2-80.  So I want to get tcm:2-80's parent, or anything that's in the tree moving up.

I've tried the GetBluePrintChain() method on a local copy of a component where it works fine. However, on shared component it returns an InvalidActionException: "This item is shared".  The documentation mentions that this exception is thrown on shared items. But how does this make sense?  Obviously if any item that has a blueprint chain beyond itself would be shared (or be a local copy).  So to me it doesn't make sense to have this method throw an exception on something that has a blueprint chain. It seems contradictory.

My question is somewhat related to [Getting root publication of component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131273/getting-root-publication-of-component), but it is different.  I need to understand why this exception is thrown on shared items.  Can someone please explain and perhaps share a use case to support it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the `GetBluePrintChain` methods are meant to look down a BluePrint when you're standing at the top of it. So in your case, you should get the item in its owning publication context and then invoke `GetBluePrintChain`.

```cs
Item item = package.GetByName("Component");
Component component = new Component(item.GetAsXmlDocument().DocumentElement,
                                    engine.GetSession());
TcmUri id = TemplateUtilities.CreateTcmUriForPublication(
        component.OwningRepository.Id.ItemId, component.Id);

var blueprintchain = ((Component)engine.GetObject(id)).GetBluePrintChain();

package.PushItem(package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, 
                                          blueprintchain.ToString()));
package.PushItem(package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text,
                             ""+System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(blueprintchain)));
foreach (var item in blueprintchain)
{
    package.PushItem(package.CreateTridionItem(ContentType.Component, item));
}
```

I just ran the above C# fragment as a TBB in two scenarios:

1. in a child publication on a shared Component
2. in a child publication on a localized Component

In case 1 the `blueprintchain` will contain a single item: the shared Component. In case 2 the `blueprintchain` will contain two items: the shared Component and the localized Component.

Comment: ah, but if you specify a filter you can set the direction up or down.  So I would expect to be able to take a shared item and get the chain up the tree:
     BluePrintChainFilter bpfilter = new BluePrintChainFilter(BluePrintChainDirection.Up, engine.GetSession());

Comment: The item can be localized in the current context repository, in which case you can look either up or down - and you specify the direction in the filter. Either way it seems like you can only access the BluePrintChain on an item in the context of its OwningRepository.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the answer above, here's a practical work-around for "Item is shared" issue:

Calling **GetBluePrintChain()** for an arbitrary item that happens to be *shared* will fail:

```cs
return
  item.GetBluePrintChain(
    new BluePrintChainFilter(
      BluePrintChainDirection.Up,
      engine.GetSession()
    )
  ).LastOrDefault();
```

The solution is to find a top-most localized item's parent first as per Frank's recipe:

```cs
return
  ((RepositoryLocalObject)engine
    .GetObject(
      TemplateUtilities.CreateTcmUriForPublication(
        item.OwningRepository.Id.ItemId,
        item.Id
      )
    )
  ).GetBluePrintChain(
    new BluePrintChainFilter(
      BluePrintChainDirection.Up,
      engine.GetSession()
    )
  ).LastOrDefault();
```